# WCF on PocketPC, not connecting to host machine

Tags: wcf, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm working with a PocketPC vm for development over here.

I can get the virtual device to connect to the internet, but I can't get it to connect to a web service on my local (host) machine.

I've tried the machine name and my IP address, different ports, but no luck.

Anyone else have this issue?

EDIT:  I have an actual device at my machine as well.  When docked I don't have this problem with the real device, just the emulated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out when I read this article:
http://www.betterthaneveryone.com/archive/2008/08/31/getting-network-access-on-the-windows-mobile-emulator.aspx

1. The device has to be docked.  You need to use the Device Emulator Manager to dock the device.  *Also note: you can only have one device docked at a given time.*
   Once the device is docked,  you should see the Windows Mobile Device Center display.  Find the running device (look for the green arrow), right-click and select Cradle.  Remember, only one device can be cradled/docked at a time.  If you have a real device that is cradled already, you cannot cradle an emulator.
2. In Windows Mobile Device Center -> Mobile Device Settings -> Connection Settings: Check "Allow connections to one of the following:" and select DMA in the dropdown.
3. On the emulator: File->Configure->Network.  Make sure a valid network device is selected.
4. From the emulated OS: Start Menu -> Settings -> Connections -> Connections -> Advanced -> Select Networks.  Make both drop-downs My ISP.

That should be it.  To test, load Internet Explorer, browse to StackOverflow.com.  Next, browse to a web page on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I have not had the specific issue.  But, the best way I've found to deal with these issues when using WCF is to [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and see what the error messages are.

Comment: The issue is not WCF specific.  I also cannot connect to any web sites with the internal browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected via ActiveSync, you can connect to the name "ppp_peer".

This name will always resolve to the machine connected via active sync.